# Bootstrap $().dropdown() not work

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is all my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" onmouseover="dropDownControl()" id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function dropDownControl() {
        $('#drop1').dropdown();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and i just what to dropdown the menu when the mouse over, but it was not working. I have test `$().dropdown('toggle')` and it can working, why `$().dropdown` can not working?

Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jquery along with bootstrap in order to get it work. Your code should look like this. I have used the javascript it's the working solution for your answer with javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Title</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" onmouseover="dropDownControl(this)"  onmouseleave="dropDownControlLeave(this)" id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function dropDownControl(e) {
                parent = e.parentElement;
                parent.classList.add("open");
                e.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
            }

            function dropDownControlLeave(e) {
                parent = e.parentElement;
                parent.classList.remove("open");
                e.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
            }
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank you @bajran, it works for me. But i still don't understand why `$().dropdown()` doesn't works

Comment: acherLj because $ is for the jquery. You don't have jquery imported in your code that's why. $ doesn't work.

Comment: @archerLj please vote up if you're satisfied with the answer.

Comment: i don't think so. why `$().dropdown('toggle')` can work?  and i'm sure $ is working okay cause there's other functions use $ and they are working.